# Android transform icon into another one

Tags: android, icons, android-animation

how can I archieve the animation of an icon being tranformed into another one, like the burger into the arrow (navigation drawer) or the pencil into the cross (inbox)? How can I archieve this animation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The icon animation can be achieved using [`animated-vector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html)

First define your icons as vector drawables. For example, let's take up a tick to cross animation as found [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud862-samples/blob/master/TickCross/). We will animate `ic_tick` to `ic_cross`.

`ic_cross.xml`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"
        android:viewportWidth="@integer/viewport_width"
        android:viewportHeight="@integer/viewport_height">

    <group
        android:name="@string/groupTickCross"
        android:pivotX="@integer/viewport_center_x"
        android:pivotY="@integer/viewport_center_y">

        <path
            android:name="@string/cross"
            android:pathData="M6.4,6.4 L17.6,17.6 M6.4,17.6 L17.6,6.4"
            android:strokeWidth="@integer/stroke_width"
            android:strokeLineCap="square"
            android:strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"/>

    </group>

</vector>
```

`ic_tick.xml`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"
        android:viewportWidth="@integer/viewport_width"
        android:viewportHeight="@integer/viewport_height">

    <group
        android:name="@string/groupTickCross"
        android:pivotX="@integer/viewport_center_x"
        android:pivotY="@integer/viewport_center_y">

        <path
            android:name="@string/tick"
            android:pathData="M4.8,13.4 L9,17.6 M10.4,16.2 L19.6,7"
            android:strokeWidth="@integer/stroke_width"
            android:strokeLineCap="square"
            android:strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"/>

    </group>

</vector>
```

Next we create animators for each of the steps. `valueFrom` tells the starting point of the animation and `valueTo` is the final product of the animation. `interpolator` is the type of interpolation, and you can find a lot more in Android docs. `duration` specifies the duration of the animation.

`tick_to_cross.xml`

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="M4.8,13.4 L9,17.6 M10.4,16.2 L19.6,7"
    android:valueTo="M6.4,6.4 L17.6,17.6 M6.4,17.6 L17.6,6.4"
    android:duration="@integer/duration"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:valueType="pathType"/>
```

Now, using animated-vector, we animate the vector. Here `<target android:name` specifies the target on which the animation has to be done, and `android:animation` tells the animation to be done.

`avd_tick_to_cross.xml`

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick">

    <target
        android:name="@string/tick"
        android:animation="@animator/tick_to_cross" />

</animated-vector>
```

There are a few limitations on how to animate between drawable vectors, but they can be hacked in some way or other, if you have a clear picture what to animate to what, and how the animation should go.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically get the icon vector xml file (ic_cross.xml or ic_tick.xml) from an image file?

Comment: @Caketray There are several tools to convert png to svg (vector xml), just  do a Google search.

Comment: Can I have control over the animation?? Like if I have a scrollbar, If I am scrolling the scrollbar then the icon should transform from one to another and if I stopped scrolling, then the transformation should not continue. Basically I want the transformation to be in my control.

Comment: Is this possible with .png images?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) created by [Alex Lockwood](https://medium.com/@alexjlockwood) to transform icon to another. You can read this [medium](https://sourcediving.com/android-recipes-the-easy-path-to-animated-icons-878bffcb0920) post and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEJeVIOBepA) to have a clear concept about ShapeShifter

Comment: whoaa that's cool man, many many thanks 

Comment: @DioLantiefWidoyoko we are most welcome bro