# Android Studio - Transform an icon to another one with an animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-icons

I want to transform an opened lock icon to a closed lock icon with an animation when a switch is checked. 
I know how to handle switch state, but have no idea on how to do the icon animation.
How to do that?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145474/android-transform-icon-into-another-one/34040874) link. Hopefully it will help you

Comment: try this https://github.com/rey5137/material

Comment: My question is specific: opened lock icon to a closed lock icon. I tried method used in those "tutorial", but they didn't worked for this case